# Issue displaying Trademark sign and more

Tags: symbols

LaTeX does not give me an error message, but if I use ™, ® or even °C I get a gibberish output such as "Âõ".

Is there any way to resolve the issue?

Comment: `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` or a proper font encoding? Unclear

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If i use the package i get the error message ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:° not set up for use with LaTeX.

Comment: Jason: I rarely use unicode characters, perhaps the font is not setup for this character so far

Comment: I see, I tried using \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} but that does not solve the problem. I'm just surprised that latex wont even recognize a simple 'degree'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `textcomp` package and apply the macros, but for Celsius `siunitx` might be better!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}
Trademark: \texttrademark

Registered: \textregistered

Celsius: \textcelsius

\end{document}
```

[image]